# Создание интернет клиента

Tags: c++

Хочу создать какой-то интернет клиент, например для twitter. Но я новичок. Что посоветуете мне прочитать, смотреть или для начала делать, чтобы осуществить такой проект? Посоветуйте мне пожалуйста, книги, статьи, видео уроки или просто дайте совет.

Answer (score 6):

Как я понимаю:

1. Изучаем язык;
2. Изучаем [библиотеку](http://code.google.com/p/curlpp/), с которой планируется организовывать работу с сетью (шаг не совсем обязательный, но желательный - см. шаг 4);
3. Изучаем API того или иного web-сервиса (# https://dev.twitter.com/);
4. Смотрим, если есть уже готовая обертка для этого API (# https://dev.twitter.com/docs/ios) на вашем языке программирования - используем ее (только если она официальная - в самопальных часто приходится еще что-то допиливать, как обычно);
5. Если же готового SDK нет - работаем напрямую с [HTTP-запросами](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#.D0.9E.D0.B1.D1.8B.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B9_GET-.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81) (+ [OAuth](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) там всякий и пр.), получаем ответ от сервера в виде  [`XML`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML)/[`JSON`](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON)/etc и парсим его самостоятельно (тут тоже проще использовать уже готовые решения - уж они для любого языка сегодня в ассортименте).
6. Если что-то не получается - всегда можно задать вопрос Гуглу: работа с web-сервисами не такая уже новая тема, так что почти со 100% вероятностью можно сказать, что те трудности, что у вас возникли испытывал кто-то до вас и (тоже весьма вероятно) нашел решение.

*P.S. все ссылки на правах рекламы.*

Comment: а для работы с сетью, новичку, что мне делать? Для ознакомления с работой с сетью?

Comment: Google << "Сокеты С++" << "Клиент-серверные приложения С++". 
Или ищите высокоуровневые библиотеки, вроде curl и пр.

Comment: а вот для изучения Visual C++ Microsoft, какое пособие посоветуешь?

Comment: Да я на C++ ни разу не писал, не знаю. Гугл подсказывает, что есть книжка 2005 года  (на русском) - можно и ее для начала - основы не должны сильно были поменяться. Ну и что-нибудь вроде http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/60k1461a.aspx - тоже на русском и информация свежее.

Comment: а на чем пишешь?

Comment: Objective-C/plain C.